# If the Jacobian of a vector field is symmetric, is the vector field a gradient?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, jacobian, hessian-matrix

Suppose I have a vector field $v$, and I am interested in knowing whether it is a potential gradient, i.e. $v = \nabla f$ for some scalar function $f$. Symmetry of the Jacobian $Dv$ is clearly necessary for this function to be a Hessian-- is this condition also sufficient for $v$ to be a gradient? (At least locally over some finite domain.)

Comment: Locally, yes - this is a special case of the Poincare lemma.  Globally, it's not necessarily sufficient; though the global obstructions tend to have more to do with whether the domain has "holes" than with whether the domain is infinite or not.